# Eval string string only if it is an assignment statement in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string with a hash table, that I would like to assign to a reference variable using Perl `eval`. Consider:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $h;
my $str=q/$h={a=>'a',b=>'b'}/;
eval($str);
if ($@) {
   print "An error occured processing the string\n";
   die $@;
}
dump($h);
```

The problem is that the string is actually supplied by the user (read from file), and I would like to prevent malicious code to be executed in the `eval`. Is it possible to check that the string only represents a variable assignment (not code like `unlink my_important_file;`)?

Comment: If you only want the user to be able to assign a variable, why are you asking them for executable code? Couldn't you just ask for the value they want you to assign to the variable?

Comment: How will checking for an assignment solve that problem? What if they supply `$var = (unlink "my_important_file");`? That's an assignment.

Comment: You should run the user-supplied code in a sandbox. Google "perl sandbox" for recommendations.

Comment: @DavidKnipe The input is a hash table. It can be arbitrarily large. Like a config file. I am not sure if it will work. If I put the assignment outside the string like `my $newstr='$h={'.$str.'};'; eval ($newstr);`, would that work? Even for the case that Barmar shows in the comment above.. Then Perl would simply give an error message?

Comment: Just ask them to supply the string as JSON, then throw whatever they supply at [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the module [Quote::Ref](https://metacpan.org/pod/Quote%3a%3aRef).

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need to evaluate user input, use [`Safe`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe). Example usage [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/perl/code/216821/an-extremely-safe-eval).